# Break lines at " -"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create separate lines `if a string contains " -"`.
But if it does not contain " -", then leave the string as it is.
So for example,

```
const string = '-Sentence one -Sentence two -Sentence three'
<div>
  {string}
</div>
```

But this string should be separated into multiple lines if there is a space followed by a hyphen.
Then what should be displayed on the website, is a few lines. Instead of one sentence.
Also, after replacing, I'd also want to reinsert the "-" as they were.

Comment: Try and use `split()`?

Comment: But I wouldn't necessary want to split a word which includes a "-", so if I do " -", it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please clarify the question with more examples? Also, do you want to render the sentences with line breaks in the HTML? @JoshuaBitton

Comment: What if you had `"-This is not-cool"`?

Comment: Yes in the html, and also, thats why i want to split after a space and "-"

Comment: @JoshuaBitton, check out my answer below. Let me know if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .replaceAll on the string, to replace `" -"` with `"\n"`

you'll need to set the `white-space` css property of the div to `pre-line`

Comment: Would you also be able to reinseert the dashes after spliting it?

Comment: I didn't tell you to split, I told you to use replace, but yes, you can replace " -" with "\n -" instead, adding a line break before the dashes

Answer (score 2):

Consider splitting, mapping, and adding the line break (`<br />`) with whatever is missing

Kinda like:

```
const string = '-Sentence one -Sentence two -Sentence three'

<div>
  {string.split(' -').map(x => <span key={somethingUnique}>-{x} <br /></span>)}
</div>
```

Comment: You're correct @NguyễnVănPhong, but I'm using a map to have more control over how each string should look after adding a line break. When you only do split and join it replaces the " -" with a <br />

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong it's in fact not the same at all since this isn't HTML, it's React's JSX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and join to do that.

Here is one liner:

```
const string = '-Sentence one -Sentence two -Sentence three';
string.split(' -').join('<br>') // if line break in html
string.split(' -').join('\n') // or this
```

Or you can run loop over the array after split and display them by adding in the required element with new line.